# Determining loss of intensity in a slow neutron beam after passing through a metal plate

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, neutrons, data

I am looking at a question dealing with the loss of intensity of a beam of slow neutrons with initial intensity $I_0 = 5 * 10^5$ N/sec as it passes through an aluminum plate that is $3$ cm thick.

I know that $I = I_0 e^{-\sigma x n} $, where $x$ is the thickness (3 cm), and $\sigma$ is the cross-section, and $n$ is the number of atoms per unit volume. My question is, where would I find information on the number of atoms per unit volume and the cross section for a given metal (in this case its aluminum, but it could just as easily be anything else).

Comment: What is the mass density of aluminum, which leads to the atomic density of aluminum (almost precisely 1/10th of a mol per cc). Cross sections vs energy can be found at your local ENDF mirror.